# como bloquear links con identity framework sin estar logueado?

Tags: c#, identity

tengo una pregunta, estoy utilizando el framework identity para mi proyecto el cuales tiene los roles admin e usuario.. El problema es que por ejemplo cuando ingreso al sistema con cualquier rol y copio algun link y cierro session y pego el link en el navegador me muestra la vista lo cual no debería. Si se estan manejando las vistas bien por roles el problema es si copio algun link y lo pego en el navegar luego sin estar logueado. Solo los crud botan el programa cuando intento ingresar a algun link sin ingresar al sistema

codigo:

```
 if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Mantenimientos</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                                <li>

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Inventario", "Index", "TInventarios")
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Partida", "Index", "TPartidas")
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Proveedor", "Index", "TProveedors")
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Solicitud/Detalle", "Index", "TSolicitudDetalles")
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Solicitud/Maestro", "Index", "TSolicitudMaestroes")
                                     @Html.ActionLink("Funcionarios","Index","copiaFuncionarios")

                                </li>
                            </ul>


                                <a href="#homeSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Reportes </a>

                                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu2">
                                    <li>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Reporte Activos", "MostrarReporteActivo", "Reporte")
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Reporte Pedimentos", "Pedimento", "Reporte")
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Reporte Articulos", "MostrarReporteArticulo", "Reporte")
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Reporte Existencia", "MostrarExistencia", "Reporte")


                                    </li>



                            </ul>


                        }
                        else if (User.IsInRole("Usuario"))
                        {
                            <a href="#homeSubmenu3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Menu</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu3">
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Informacion Articulos", "Observar", "TArticuloes")
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Informacion Proveedores", "Observar", "TProveedors")

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        }

                    }

                </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad la logica de restringir el acceso a las vistas en caso de no estar logeado debe ser llevada en el controlador y cada una de sus acciones usando la anotacion `[Authorize]`, de la siguiente manera, en conjunto con la activacion de la autenticacion y la authorizacion en `Startup.cs`.

A nivel de controlador:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Perfil()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

A nivel de vista

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Perfil()
    {
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

y en la clase `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
    });
}
```

Comment: que grande, gracias!!!

Comment: podrias aceptar mi respuesta? 

Comment: listo!!!!!!!!!!!!!